# Transmit power of sender mobile

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless

In my application i want to know **the transmit power** of a mobile phone when i received from it data (beacon, file, ..). I need to know the transmit power, to use it in distance calculations using **Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI)**.

How i can do that?

Comment: Are you using direct wifi or phone as wireless hotspot? Cause Reading RSSI from packages sent through normal wireless gateway, will tell you the RSSI between phone and gateway.

Comment: Regardless it is wifi direct or hotspot, i know i can read RSSI, but in addition to the RSSI value i need the transmit power of the sender

Comment: On scale of 0-100, RSSI can be roughly changed to dbm using
dbm = ((Rssi/3)-100);

Comment: may you don't understand me, i want the value of the transmit power of the sender before it send

Comment: I don't think any RF protocol sends that information. Transmit power also varies between individual devices. But if you want the transmit power usually in Wifi, it's 100mW. Transmit power cannot really be used to calculate locations and distances. You can use loss of signal (dampening) to measure distances. Maybe I still do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks @Gjordis, firstly yes since it varies between individual devices, isn't stored in any place in each device, so i can reach it?      secondly, how i can use loss of signal to measure distance? can you explain to me. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to measure distance using signal dampening:

There are different way of doing this. The most basic way is using open space dampening, where you get reference values inside a certain space, e.g a room. Any new furniture or change in surface material affect these values. This document is some guys thesis or something about the subject, you might want to check this out: http://www.s2is.org/Issues/v1/n2/papers/paper14.pdf. Good location is difficult especially, because the dampening is not linear.

This function is for theoretican dampening in open space:

```
L = 20 log(d) + 20 log(f) + 36.6,
```

where L is dampening in Db
f is frequency in MHz
and d is distance in miles.

This is the radio theory